# Backup postgresql database using SQL only

Tags: postgresql

In Microsoft SQL Server, it just simple to backup database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE my_database TO DISK my_zip_file
```

Is it possible to backup PostgreSQL (9.0.1) database as a simple is that?

If posible, what is the script?

Comment: No there is no SQL statement to do that, only commandline tools.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: so there the other way to do that?

Comment: Btw: why are you using such an outdated Postgres version? 9.0 would be like using SQL Server 2005 today.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually how to know my postgres version? Start | Programs | Postgresql 9.0 | pgAdmin III | Help | About, but I dont see postgresql version. I just see it on postgresql documentation, but still wondering is it actually this version or not

Comment: I only see 'Version 1.12.1' not like 'Version 9.0.xx' or something. If i uninstall it then install new postgrsql, is it my database missing or not?

Comment: That is the version of pgAdmin not the Postgres version. Run `select version()` to see the server version.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in PostgreSQL. You need to do it using the `pg_dump` shell command, which makes its own connection to PostgreSQL, or using a tool like `pg_basebackup` if you want a physical DB copy. [Supported backup methods are documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html).

You can stream individual tables to the client via `COPY`, but that's about it.

I'd be nice if the DB supported backup over the database protocol, but it doesn't, and there's no work currently happening to add such a feature. For this sort of thing what's needed is a person or team who really wants the feature, and is willing to put in the time required to develop it, or fund others to develop it. For "utility" features like this, there usually isn't anyone willing to step up and do the work or fund it.

Search for "libpgdump", "postgresql server-side dump", "pg_dump library", etc to learn more about past discussions on this topic.

(Even if it did, it wouldn't support it in the old, known-buggy version you're using. You're 14 patch releases behind, update to 9.0.15.)

Comment: Thanks, I already read the backup methods in the manual, but it's hard to understand for beginner like me. Confused by term and term. Ooo...so many obstacle in postgresql. No backup easily, no datediff easily... ow maaan

Comment: @user3239588: the backup is as easy as `pg_dump --format=c --file=db.pgdmp databasename` I don't see how that would be harder than writing `BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK db.pgdump` (just on a different commandline).

Comment: @user3239588 "no datediff easily". Um. `date2 - date1`. What's hard about that? "Different to MS SQL Server" is not the same as "hard". Though I agree it is sometimes frustrating that you can't dump object definitions, or whole database backups, over the wire protocol. Most of the time it turns out not to matter, it's only a few cases where invoking `pg_dump` is any problem at all.

Comment: #### MS SQL Server #### `SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2011-12-30 08:54:55', '2011-12-30 08:56:10');`   #### POSTGRESQL #### 'SELECT ((DATE_PART('day', '2011-12-30 08:56:10'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp) * 24 + 
                DATE_PART('hour', '2011-12-30 08:56:10'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('minute', '2011-12-30 08:56:10'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('second', '2011-12-30 08:56:10'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp);`  Watchout the ')' or get wrong value !!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: i just need to write `pg_dump --format=c --file=my_zip_file my_database` for backup ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can I do it runtime when application run ?

Comment: @user3239588: yes that's all. You also need to specify username and password but that's about it. And yes it's a transactional snapshot, please read the manual it's all documented there. Your "complicated datediff" can be replaced with `SELECT extract(epoch from '2011-12-30 08:56:10'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp)`.

Comment: @user3239588 extract(epoch from (timestamp '2013-01-29 15:00' - timestamp '2013-01-29 14:00')) ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for datediff postgres version. I will continue on backup part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I run the `pg_dump --format=c --file=my_zip_file my_database` in pgAdmin III | SQL Editor but comes out with error

Comment: @postgreat First, never say "it comes out with error". *Always give a specific error message*. Second, that's not an SQL command, so you cannot run it in an SQL editor. It's a regular commandline program. That's the whole point.

Comment: @CraigRinger where is the commandline program, so i can run the script?

Comment: @postgreat It's `pg_dump.exe` and it's in the PostgreSQL install directory, in the `bin` folder.

Comment: @CraigRinger Is password pg_dump.exe same as password database? pg_dump said 'pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database 'xxx' failed: FATAL: password authentication fail for user 'xxx''

Comment: @postgreat It makes a PostgreSQL connection, so it follows all the same rules as any other `libpq` based application. Please see the documentation for more information: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html

Comment: @postgreat I won't be replying to further comments on this thread, by the way. If you have further questions please post new questions on stack overflow *after doing appropriate reading and research*.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Ow, that's italic words is so rude. I was reading and researched it before, just for your information.